# How to replace bracket in vim?

Tags: substitute

I have

```
"012-0738-32"],[ "4", "Beacon
```

I want

```
"012-0738-32"
"4", "Beacon
```

`],[`+ `space` replaced with `\r`

Comment: Did you try to use the `:s` command? Or anything else? Did you get stuck somewhere? It's better to post what you've tried, so that people can point out what your mistake was, rather than just provide a "here copy this"-sort of answer.

Answer (score 9):

You need to escape the opening square bracket: `:s/],\[ /\r`

Comment: Thank you @Luc Hermitte. For all line in a file `:%s/],\[ /\r`

Answer (score 3):

A visual way to handle this is to

**1) search**:

<kbd>/</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>

**2) select the matched text**

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>

**3) substitute text**

<kbd>s</kbd>  and insert the text you want

**4) Repeat if needed**

You can advance to next match using  <kbd>n</kbd>  then  <kbd>.</kbd>  to repeat your last substitution.